# Usar una variable de una function en otra con javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, javascript-objeto, javascript-metodo, javascript-import

estoy intentando hacer que al usuario se le solicite que introduzca una frase cualquiera, al apretar un botón, y que esta frase se repita un maximo de 3 veces, ademas de un boton para detener esta repeticion que se hace cada 3 segundos... tengo todo lo mencionado anteriormente pero el problema esta en que en mi codigo pide la frase al iniciar el sitio, y lo que necesito es que lo pida al apretar el boton, adjunto mi codigo

'''

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bucle</title>
</head>
<body> 

    <h1>BIENVENIDO A SU REPETIDOR DE FRASE :D</h1>
    
    <div>
        <button class="start" onclick="temporizadorDeRetraso()">Comienza el juego</button>
        <button class="end" onclick="borrarAlerta()">Parar de jugar</button>

        <div id="frase">

        </div>

    </div>
```

'''
aqui le añadi un poco de forma a los botones
'''

```
    <style>
        .start, .end{
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            padding: 10 px;
        }
        .start:hover, .end:hover{
            background-color: rgb(222, 128, 128);
            color: black;
            padding: 10 px;
        }
        #frase{
            background-color: rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.068);
            padding: 25px;
            margin: 25px;
            color: black;
        }
    </style>
```

'''
y aqui empieza mi problema con javascript
'''

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         
        var identificadorDeTemporizador;
        var i = 3;
        var y = prompt("ingrese su frase");

        function temporizadorDeRetraso() {
            identificadorDeTemporizador = setInterval(funcionConRetraso, 3000);  
        }

        

        function funcionConRetraso() {
                var newt = document.createElement("div"); 
                newt.style.cssText='border:8px solid #56aaf3;padding:12px;width:160px;margin:12px 0 12px 0; text-align:center;'; //se le asigan caracteristicas css al div creado                 
                var t = document.createTextNode("" + y);       
                newt.appendChild(t);  
                document.getElementById("frase").appendChild(newt);                      
                  var z = i--; 

                if(i == 0){
                    clearInterval(identificadorDeTemporizador);
                }
        }

        function borrarAlerta() {
            alert ("BASTA!");
            clearInterval(identificadorDeTemporizador);
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bastaría con declarar / asignar la variable `var y = prompt("ingrese su frase");` dentro de la `funcionConRetraso()`.

Por otra parte, te recomendaría que:

- pongas siempre las reglas de estilo en el `.css` y luego asignes la clase al `div` con `className`
- uses [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) para añadir elementos al DOM
- declares una sola vez la referencia al elemento con id `frase`

Y es que las llamadas al DOM, o las modificaciones del DOM son costosas. Quizá aquí no se note demasiado, pero por ejemplo en código muy repetitivo, esta mala práctica puede tener consecuencias en cuanto al rendimiento.

Algo así:

```js
var identificadorDeTemporizador;
var i = 3;
let divFrase = document.getElementById("frase");
let frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

function temporizadorDeRetraso() {
  identificadorDeTemporizador = setInterval(funcionConRetraso, 3000);
}

function funcionConRetraso() {
  var y = prompt("ingrese su frase");
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.className = "newDiv";
  var t = document.createTextNode(y);
  newDiv.appendChild(t);
  frag.appendChild(newDiv);
  divFrase.appendChild(frag);
  var z = i--;
  if (i == 0) {
    clearInterval(identificadorDeTemporizador);
  }
}

function borrarAlerta() {
  alert("BASTA!");
  clearInterval(identificadorDeTemporizador);
}
```

```css
.start,
.end {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10 px;
}

.start:hover,
.end:hover {
  background-color: rgb(222, 128, 128);
  color: black;
  padding: 10 px;
}

#frase {
  background-color: rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.068);
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 25px;
  color: black;
}

.newDiv {
  border: 8px solid #56aaf3;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 160px;
  margin: 12px 0 12px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bucle</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>BIENVENIDO A SU REPETIDOR DE FRASE :D</h1>

  <div>
    <button class="start" onclick="temporizadorDeRetraso()">Comienza el juego</button>
    <button class="end" onclick="borrarAlerta()">Parar de jugar</button>

    <div id="frase">

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si comprendo bien lo que buscas, necesitas pedir el valor al usuario al pulsar el botón para iniciar el juego y seguir imprimiendo ese mismo valor, con un temporizador, hasta 3 veces.

Lo he escrito de esa manera, porque es más o menos la manera en la que hay que implementarlo.

He hecho los siguientes cambios a tu código:

- Renombrado de variables y de funciones, para que el código sea más fácil de leer.
- En el bloque principal declaro la variable `mensaje`, para que pueda ser referenciada desde las distintas rutinas conservando su valor entre llamadas.
- Pido el valor al usuario en la función `iniciarJuego()`, dónde también se inicializa la variable `i`. Esto permitirá que se pueda jugar varias veces. Asumí que esta es la intención, aunque no queda del todo claro en la pregunta.
- He mantenido la estructura básica de la rutina `agregarMensaje()`. Hay varias recomendaciones en la [respuesta de A.Cedano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/591924/21) que creo que debes de seguir.

  Lo que si cambié es la declaración y uso de la variable `z`, ya que no hace falta, como puedes observar en el código.
- En la rutina `terminarJuego()` he dado vuelta a las instrucciones, terminando primero el temporizador. De otra manera, el *juego* seguirá imprimiendo mensajes mientras el usuario presiona el OK de la alerta.

```js
var idTemporizadorMensaje;
var i = 3;
var mensaje;

function iniciarJuego() {
  mensaje = prompt("ingrese su frase");
  i = 3;
  idTemporizadorMensaje = setInterval(agregarMensaje, 3000);  
}

function agregarMensaje() {
  var newt = document.createElement("div"); 
  newt.style.cssText='border:8px solid #56aaf3;padding:12px;width:160px;margin:12px 0 12px 0; text-align:center;'; //se le asigan caracteristicas css al div creado                 
  var t = document.createTextNode("" + mensaje);       
  newt.appendChild(t);  
  document.getElementById("frase").appendChild(newt);                      
  if(--i == 0){
    clearInterval(idTemporizadorMensaje);
  }
}

function terminarJuego() {
  clearInterval(idTemporizadorMensaje);
  alert ("BASTA!");
}
```

```css
.start, .end{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10 px;
}
.start:hover, .end:hover{
  background-color: rgb(222, 128, 128);
  color: black;
  padding: 10 px;
}
#frase{
  background-color: rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.068);
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 25px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<h1>BIENVENIDO A SU REPETIDOR DE FRASE :D</h1>
<div>
  <button class="start" onclick="iniciarJuego()">Comienza el juego</button>
  <button class="end" onclick="terminarJuego()">Parar de jugar</button>
  <div id="frase"></div>
</div>
```

He dejado todo en un *snippet* para que puedas probarlo aquí mismo, haciendo clic en el botón *Ejecutar*.